Не могу запустить сборку на ios React Native
Пытаюсь запустить сборку на IOS, на эмуляторе, проект на React Native, но получаю бесконечную загрузку, гуглил, в гугле ничего не нашел, пробовал запускать через xcode, там висят ошибки с либами, вот лог, что я делал ранее
info React Native v0.73.6 is now available (your project is running on v0.73.2).
info Changelog: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.73.6
info Diff: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.73.6
info For more info, check out "https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading?os=macos".
info Dev server ready

i - run on iOS
a - run on Android
d - open Dev Menu
r - reload app

info Opening app on iOS...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Found Xcode workspace "Helper.xcworkspace"
info Found booted iPhone SE (3rd generation)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace Helper.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Helper -destination id=23B70323-7785-45DD-A1C5-D242C5D1FD7D")

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Helper.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Helper -destination id=23B70323-7785-45DD-A1C5-D242C5D1FD7D

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (90 targets)
    Target 'Helper' in project 'Helper'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-Helper' in project 'Pods' via file 'libPods-Helper.a' in build phase 'Link Binary'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'AppAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-lAppAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'BVLinearGradient' in project 'Pods' via options '-lBVLinearGradient' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lCocoaAsyncSocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-lDoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Boost-iOSX' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Fmt' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Fmt' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipper-PeerTalk' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FlipperKit' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFlipperKit' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GTMAppAuth' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGTMAppAuth' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GTMSessionFetcher' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGTMSessionFetcher' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleSignIn' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGoogleSignIn' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCT-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNAudioRecorderPlayer' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNAudioRecorderPlayer' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCAsyncStorage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCAsyncStorage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCClipboard' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCClipboard' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFastImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFastImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFlashList' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFlashList' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGoogleSignin' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNGoogleSignin' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNPermissions' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNPermissions' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNSVG' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNSVG' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Core' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Fabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Fabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-FabricImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-FabricImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-ImageManager' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-ImageManager' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Mapbuffer' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Mapbuffer' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-NativeModulesApple' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-NativeModulesApple' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAppDelegate' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTFabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTFabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-debug' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-debug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-graphics' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-graphics' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-hermes' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-hermes' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jserrorhandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jserrorhandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsi' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi

В xcode висят такие ошибки:



1.В Xcode нужно найти файл FlipperTransportTypes.h
2. Добавить импор #include 

Спасибо! Очень помогли
